# Cambiar tamano a un scroll con boostrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola mi problema es que tengo una lista de hostales y al lado un mapa y quiero que la lista de hostales se pueda scrolear y que el resto de la pagina no se mueva( lo siento si no me e explicado bien ), la cosa es que ya cree el menú con scroll pero es muy pequeño y no se como cambiar el tamaño de ese menú, dejo el código

```
<div class="row mt-4">
   <div class="col-6" style="height: 100%">
       <div class="pre-scrollable">
           <div class="bg-light">
               {% for hostal in hostales %}
                   <div clss="ScrolHostales mx-2">
                       <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 shadow bg-light rounded h-md-250 ">
                           <img class="card-img-right flex-auto d-none d-md-block" data-src="holder.js/200x250?theme=thumb" src="../static/img/HostalPic/{{ hostal.foto }}" style="height: 250px; width: 330px">
                           <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
                               <h3 class="mb-0">
                                   <a class="text-dark" href="/buscar/{{hostal.id}}"> {{ hostal.nombre }} </a>
                               </h3>
                               <div class="mb-1 text-muted">{{ hostal.ubicacion }}</div>
                                   <p class="card-text mb-auto">
                                                                {{ hostal.descripcion }}
                                    </p>
                                    <span class="text-primary "> $ {{ hostal.precio}} </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 <div class="col-6">
     <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d12775.097738508905!2d-73.01716441173096!3d-36.82392475928676!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2scl!4v1561174357817!5m2!1ses-419!2scl"frameborder="0" style="border:0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

Quedo muy descuadrado pero espero que se entienda. Gracias de antemano <3.

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer tienes mal los div de cierre, mira esta opción. El contenedor de tu lista lo encierras con un `div` de `height:90vh`, y tu lista la dejas con `overflow-y:scroll;max-height:100%`, usas bootstrap con la clases `col-6` ya estas listo, con esos tendrás 2 columnas en pantalla , podrás hacer scroll en la lista sin que esta se sobresalga de la pantalla. ( opción extra es al listado agregarle `width: calc(100% + 30px );` esto ocultara el scroll en web para que sea mas limpio )

```css
.lista {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 90vh; // determino el tamaño de la lista
  max-height: 90vh; // para nunca sea mayor a la pantalla
}

.lista__body {
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.lista__body--hidde_scroll {
   width: calc(100% + 30px );
}

.lista__item {
  height: 250px; 
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body>

<div class="main row">
  <div class="main__lista lista col-6">
    <div class="lista__body lista__body--hidde_scroll">
        <li class="lista__item">ITEM</li>
        <li class="lista__item">ITEM</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main__mapa col-6">
    <h1>Soy el Mapa</h1>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad, por favor visita [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)